# React native build to device failed

Tags: ios, build, react-native

I'm trying to build to an iOS device, building to simulator works fine.
This is what I get:

> uncaught error Error: TypeError: unsupported file type at lookup (/Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app react/VexAppReact/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:35:9)
>   at /Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app-react/VexAppReact/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:93:22
>   at /Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app-react/VexAppReact/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:50:9
>   at /Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app-react/VexAppReact/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:43:10
>   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
>   See logs /var/folders/h8/42h3w_qd2r9fvpwy99jsnjq40000gn/T/react-packager.log
>   at SocketClient._handleMessage (SocketClient.js:144:23)
>   at BunserBuf. (SocketClient.js:53:42)
>   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
>   at BunserBuf.emit (events.js:182:7)
>   at BunserBuf.process (/Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app-react/VexAppReact/node_modules/bser/index.js:289:10)
>   at /Users/NAME/git/vex/vex-app react/VexAppReact/node_modules/bser/index.js:244:12
>   at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
>   at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

I'm assuming there's something wrong with image assets. I didn't install the `image-size` node module myself, so I doubt there's something wrong with that module, it could be though.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: apparently you can't add png files to native ios build

Comment: Hey @Harbinger I had removed images.xcassets and added all the images in a folder with name images but still I m getting same error :(